# MySQL and window functions

Tags: mysql, window-functions

It seems that `MySQL` does not support window functions.
E.g. the simple: `COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt` does not work.
What I am not sure is if this applies to commercial version as well (I assume the community version is limited subset).
If not, how does one work around this missing feature?

Comment: The community edition of MySQL Server is not a limited subset in any meaningful sense.  The differences are in add-ons and plugins that do not affect core functionality.

Comment: Have a look at this workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/532941/314291) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function)

Comment: Actually, MySQL9 supports it. I have been using pandas instead which kind of sucks.

Comment: MySQL 8 supports window function. For reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Comment: MySQL supports window functions since version 8.0. This [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/) might help.

Answer (score 36):

MySQL does not support Window Functions(*). There is what we call "a poor man's window function" in the form of [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

There are plenty of tricks using `GROUP_CONCAT` to emulate window functions. They are not as pretty (syntactically) and are sometimes too limited. I've written a few. See my blog post [complaining about the missing window functions](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/three-wishes-for-a-new-year-201), and linking to various solutions based on `GROUP_CONCAT`.

In particular, [Selecting a specific non aggregated column data in GROUP BY](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/selecting-a-specific-non-aggregated-column-data-in-group-by) and [SQL: selecting top N records per group, another solution](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-selecting-top-n-records-per-group-another-solution) might be of interest to you and could give you a kick start.

Things you should note about `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

- Can use `DISTINCT`
- Can use `ORDER BY ... ASC/DESC`
- Can set `SEPARATOR`
- As any aggregation function - it discards NULL values; plenty tricks on that.

(*) Support for Window Functions has been added in MySQL 8

Comment: MySQL supports window functions as of Version 8

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is not a window function, it is an ordered set function.

Comment: @SQLRaptor no one claimed it is.

Answer (score 12):

It really should be noted that MariaDB 10.2 (released in 2017 May) has [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-functions/). That's certainly one avenue to pursue if you need MySQL and window functions.