# Difficulty with nested query order & grouping

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to identify the count of objects a user updated during a given day, but only where the user was the final update.

Each object can have multiple updates in a day from any user, but the final update is the one that should be counted.

Each object only has 1 status though--always as a result of the most recent update.

**Object_Update_Table**

```
|UpdateID| UserID |timestamp| ObjectID |
| 1      |   3    | today   |    1     |
| 2      |   3    | today   |    2     |
| 3      |   1    | today   |    3     |
| 4      |   1    | today   |    3     |
| 5      |   1    | today   |    1     |
```

**Object_Table**

```
|ObjectID| Status  |
| 1      | failed  |
| 2      | failed  |
| 3      | progress|
```

**Final desired output of query**

```
|User |count "failed"|
| 1   |  1           |
| 2   |  0           |
| 3   |  1           |
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing can be done fairly elegantly using [Window Functions](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1).  While I was researching this answer, I found that MySQL doesn't support [them](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/mysql-and-window-functions).  The code that follows is will likely have some performance problems since it uses nested `GROUP BY` select statements.  Proceed with caution.

```
SELECT UserID
     -- potentially add a date column here
     , sum(Counter) Updates
FROM (   
     SELECT UserID
          , ObjectID
          --- potentially add a date column here
          , 1 Counter
     FROM Object_Update_Table OUT inner join 
          (
          SELECT ObjectID
               -- potentially add a date column here
               , max(timestamp)
          FROM Object_Update_Table OUT
          WHERE timestamp >= today 00:00:00
                AND timestamp < tomorrow
          -- if you add a date column, you'll need to add a GROUP BY clause with the date column here
          ) last_update_day ON OUT.ObjectID = last_update_day.ObjectID
                           AND OUT.timestamp = last_update_day.timestamp
     ) Join_Back_User
GROUP BY Join_Back_User.UserID
     --, potentially add a date column here
```

The case above only works for one day due to the `WHERE` clause in line 12 and 13.  If you need to do this for more than one day at a time, you should add a function which returns the date to the inner-most sub-query and then carry that date in the `Join_Back_User` subquery to the outermost query...