# efficient way to query for count totals

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has two columns:

`user_id int(11)`
`friend_id int(11)`

In order to get the number of friends a user has has, I'd do something like:

`SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS num_friends FROM friends WHERE friend_id = some_id`

What I want to do is get the number of friends every single user in the table has and cache the results to another table so I don't have to run an expensive query like the one above. Basically a 'rollup'.

What's the best way to query for this data to get the number of friends that every `friend_id` has? I was thinking something like this, but it seems very wrong, especially if you have a large amount of distinct `friend_id` instances in the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) num_friends, friend_id FROM friends WHERE friend_id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(friend_id) FROM FRIENDS) GROUP BY friend_id
```

Comment: What you are looking for might be window function, which I believe still doesn't exist for MySQL.  See this similar question for lead....https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/mysql-and-window-functions

Comment: Heh, I was writing an answer to that INT-LIKE question when you deleted it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT friend_id, COUNT(*)
    FROM num_friends
    GROUP BY friend_id;
```

This will assist in making it fast:

```
INDEX(friend_id)
```

With that index, you will find out that the original query is so fast that you don't need to cache the results.